# using ampersand doesnt emit process number in OpenWRT linux

Tags: python, linux, openwrt

Since I am linux user, I often use `&` at the end when running the process,

I have arduin Yun shield, I am noticing when I run `python arduino_yun_python_code.py &` it doesn't spits process number , and neither I can use `ps -ef` it results in below message:
`ps: invalid option -- e` but instead I can use `ps w | grep python` why is this difference ?

Comment: OpenWRT means busybox for most of the interactive userland utilities; it has a limited number of options to allow for its very compact size. I'm not sure, but try `jobs -l` to see the status of background jobs, along with pids.

Comment: @9000 no man `jobs -l` returns nothing

Comment: Do you have anything running at that moment? It only lists jobs started from the current shell. Try running `sleep 10 &` before that.